# How to print values of multiple variables in one Console.WriteLine() statement?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have three variables, `firstName`, `middleName` and `lastName`. I am reading the values of these three variables one by one as shown in the code below. I want to print the values of the three variables in one `Console.WriteLine()` statement. The output should be in the following way:

Let,
firstName be: John; middleName be: Bradshaw; lastName be: Layfield

Output: John Bradshaw Layfield

Code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter First Name");
firstName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("\n");

Console.WriteLine("Enter Middle Name");
middleName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("\n");

enter code hereConsole.WriteLine("Enter Last Name");
lastName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("\n");
```

Comment: Use + or {#}, see this for more details: https://www.dotnetperls.com/console

Comment: you can simply use the string concatination as Console.writeLine(firstName+" "+MiddleName+" "+LastName) or string.format as Console.writeLine(String.format("{0} {1} {2}",FirstName,MiddleName,LastName));

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use `string.Format` to format your string with all 3 variables:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", firstName, middleName, lastName));
```

You should use `String Interpolation` as of C# 6.0 to format your string with all 3 variables:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{firstName} {middleName} {lastName}");
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine has an overload which calls string.Format for you. If you just remove `string.Format` (and optionally one set of parens) the result would be the same...

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the newer string interpolation method:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{firstName} {middleName} {lastName}");
```